# How do I add a picture to a Contact record from File upload

Tags: administration, files, salesforce-classic

I would like to add a picture to a Contact by uploading it to the Files related list and have the file picked up automatically, i.e. if we use the same file name for each Contact, "ContactPhoto.jpg." We are a nonprofit using Salesforce Classic.

I was thinking of:

1. List item creating a custom formula field to look up the File by name (what do I query?)
2. Grab/store document (record) ID (do I need to store this?)
3. Use record ID to display image in a text formula field:

```
   <img src="&'"'&"/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=Image_Document_ID__c"&'"'&" alt="&'"'&"Name"&'"'&" border="&'"'&"0"&'"'&"/>
```